# Как использовать getString в отдельных классах?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

Надо в отдельном классе получить текст из *values/strings*.
Класс находится не в *Activity*, а в отдельном файле.

```
class Subject {
    val s = getString(R.string.defaultName)
}
```

*getString* считается ошибкой.

Comment: потому что getString вызывается только на контексте.

Comment: как добавить контекст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передайте контекст в конструктор вашего класса `Subject`:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context

class Subject(context: Context) {
    val s = context.getString(R.string.defaultName)
}
```